# javascript order of execution

Tags: javascript

```
var c = false;
if(c=[] && c.length==0)alert('hi');
```

hi is not alerted because c is still false when it executes the second operand of &&, can someone explain how the boolean operands in if condition are executed and in what order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is just a precedence issue - `&&` is binding tighter than `=`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (c = ([] && c.length == 0))
{
    alert('hi');
}
```

So it's assigning `c` the value `false` rather than the empty array.

Try this instead:

```
if ((c = []) && c.length == 0)
{
    alert('hi');
}
```

EDIT: To address Tryptich's comment - I did try this before posting :) As CMS said, an empty array is considered true. Try this:

```
if (c = [])
{
    alert('empty array is true');
}
```

or even just this:

```
if ([])
{
    alert('empty array is true');
}
```

I checked the spec before posting - I was somewhat surprised that an empty array is considered true, but it is...

Comment: The alert still wouldn't run in your second example, because in Javascript an empty array is a false-like value. (`[]==false`) is true.

Comment: Triptych: An empty Array is not considered a false-like value, your example is a *quirk* of the equals operator, try: `!![] == true;`, `![] == false;`, `[] == false;`

Comment: Good edit Jon, BTW *everything* except, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, an empty-string (and of course `false`) evaluate to `true` in a boolean expression.